# How to do += operation in Erlang?

Tags: erlang

I'm new to Erlang. I've learned a little Python. In Python, `+=` operator is very common and convenient. e.g. `a += b` equals `a = a + b`. I know Erlang is a functional programming language. Variables in Erlang are immutable. So how to do `+=` such operation in Erlang?

Comment: Just declare a new variable? `A2 = A + B`.

Comment: The real heart of this confusion relates to your context. Yes, Erlang has single assignment, so with that in mind what is the overall effect you need to achieve? Show some Python code example and we can provide an equivalent. Sometimes this helps more than asking how to emulate an operator from lang X that does not exist in lang Y.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Erlang uses immutable variables, this cannot be done. If you are incrementing inside a loop there are techniques to do it. But if you are just incrementing the value, you need to declare a new variable like:

```
A = 5.
B = 1.
A1 = A + B.
```

Comment: In imperative programming language, for loops are always used. We declare a variable i as a counter. incrementing or decrementing in every loop. How to do this in Erlang? Thank you!

Comment: Correct @clicli, in Erlang, since variables are immutable, there are no iterators. You basically need to do a recursion, calling the same function again, i recommend you to read http://learnyousomeerlang.com/recursion

Comment: Something like:

`increment(Number) -> increment(Number + 1).`

That will not stop the loop never, in case you know when you wanna stop just need to define the same function with the number you wanna stop at as the parameter and return something like `ok.`

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

You don't. There is not an `a` and `b=/=0` for which `a=a+b`. So unless `b` is zero you can't make `a` equals `a` plus `b`. If `b` is zero then `a=a+0` which is `a=a`. I think everybody knows it.

Comment: So how to do such thing in Erlang? Need to declare a new variable?

Comment: @clicli: Yes, of course. It is immutability of variables and data structures in Erlang.

Answer (score 0):

In Erlang, you NEVER can "a += b" or something like this. It's hard for beginner to learn or migrate their code from another programming language, but It's suitable for you that never care about variables be changed in your application or process and It's always immutable.